# Get an Array with random numbers to compare numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to get my Array with ramdom numbers to Comparer the 10 first digtes and tell what if it's higher, lower or equel to the 11th number, i have tried alot of loops and many other things, but im stuck at this point.

```
private static int[] anArray;

    public static int[] list() {
        anArray = new int[11];
        for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
            anArray[i] = (int) randomFill();
        }
        return anArray;
    }

    public static void print() {
        for (int n : anArray) {
            System.out.print(n + " | ");

        }
    }

    public static int randomFill() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(15);
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        list();
        print();
    }
```

I hope that one of you can help me get on with my problem.

I know that i need to add somthing around:

```
 public static int randomFill() {
    Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(15);
        return randomNum;
    }
```

this point, and print something out, but i can't to do what i need it to do

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Also no need to cast the return result from `randomFill()` to int since it returns an int.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ --- You've successfully created and printed an array of 11 random numbers, but I see no attempt whatsoever of trying to compare the 11th number to the other numbers. --- Don't know why you think you need to add something around `randomFill()`. You don't. You need to add another method with the code doing the comparing.

Comment: Also why even use `randomFill()` when you could simply create a Random object and re-use it?

Comment: You’re doing nothing with the return value of `list()`

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` object every time you call `randomFill`.  Create one static `Random` and then keep using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int[] createRandomArray(int arraySize) {
    return new Random().ints(arraySize, 0, 100).toArray();
}
```

It will return int[] array of size 'arraySize' filled with random numbers. The numbers will range from 0 to 100.